# For x in "hello" print a y of underscores

Tags: python, list, random

I am working on a basic project for a stickman game.
My code so far is:

```
import random

list_of_words = ["Hello"]
word = str(random.choice(list_of_words))
char = int(len(word))
```

Since I am still working on it, I am only using 1 word instead of many which could complicate things more.

So how this should work is; there is a list of words. One of them gets randomly picked. Then it counts the amount of characters in the word. Lastly, it prints a certain number of underscores depending on the number of characters in the word.

In theory, if correct, it should work like this:

Word = Hello

Number of characters = 5

Result: _____ (5 underscores in one line)

Comment: Perhaps `print('_'*len(word))`?

Comment: also, in code above, `str` and `int` conversions are basically redundant.

Comment: What do you mean by "a y"? Do you mean "that many"?

Comment: Do you mean hangman? When I hear "stickman game", I think Henry Stickmin or Stick Fight. If you are trying to do hangman, the algorithm for printing underscores is going to be more complicated than this. You'd want a `set` of guessed letters, to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the call to `str()` and then generate a string of underscores that has the same length as the original string by using `'_' * len(word)`.

```py
import random

list_of_words = ["Hello"]
word = random.choice(list_of_words)
print('_' * len(word))
```

This outputs:

```py
_____
```